# foreach() is taking too much time to generate html in php

Tags: php, html

I am creating an HTML table with Ajax. But on server side the `foreach()` is taking too much time nearly 45 sec to generate the HTML (from database ).

Please advise me how to reduce this time .
I have max 1200 record in the database mean `count($result) //output 1200`

please take a look at my php code -:

```
    $html_td = $html = $html_th = "";
    $i=0;
    foreach ($result as $record) {
        $i++;
        $html_td .=  "<tr data-Year='".$record->year."'>";
        //$html_td .=  "<td>".$i."</td>";
        $html_td .=  "<td title='".$record->recipient_name."' class='masterTooltip' >".$record->recipient_name."</td>";
        $html_td .= "<td title='".$record->year."' class='masterTooltip' >".$record->year."</td>";
        $html_td .= "<td title='".strtoupper($record->title)." -: ".$record->long_description."' class='masterTooltip' >".substr($record->title,0,30).'....'."</td>";
        $html_td .= "<td title='".$record->sector."' class='masterTooltip'  >".substr($record->sector,0,20)."</td>";
        $html_td .= "<td title='".$record->region."' class='masterTooltip'  >".$record->region."</td>";
        $html_td .= "<td title='".$record->commitment_million_inr."' style='width:65px'  class='masterTooltip' >".$record->commitment_million_inr."</td>";

        if($_POST['commitment_usd_million'] == True){
            $html_td .= "<td title='".$record->commitment_usd_million."'  class='masterTooltip' >".$record->commitment_usd_million."</td>";
        }
        if($_POST['expenditure_inr_million'] == True){
            $html_td .= "<td title='".$record->expenditure_inr_million."'  class='masterTooltip' >".$record->expenditure_inr_million."</td>";
        }

        if($_POST['expenditure_usd_million'] == True){
            $html_td .= "<td title='".$record->expenditure_usd_million."'  class='masterTooltip' >".$record->expenditure_usd_million."</td>";
        }
        if($_POST['aiddata_purpose_code'] == True){
            $html_td .= "<td title='".$record->aiddata_purpose_code."'  class='masterTooltip' >".$record->aiddata_purpose_code."</td>";
        }
        if($_POST['aiddata_purpose_description'] == True){
            $html_td .= "<td title='".$record->aiddata_purpose_description."'  class='masterTooltip' >".$record->aiddata_purpose_description."</td>";
        }
        $html_td .=  "</tr>";
    }
    echo "response";die();
```

Comment: So you've profiled this, and identified that it's somewhere in the foreach loop, rather than (for example) the database query, or anywhere else in your code?

Comment: yes it is just because of foreach

Comment: So how much of that 45 seconds is taken by the database query, and how much is the foreach loop taking?

Comment: if i am commenting the foreach than the ajax time is below 1 second

Comment: you need pagination for that, 30 records max, then user clicks on more now use ajax or reload page to bring other 30 records and so on

Comment: Refer http://www.phpbench.com/

Comment: @RyanVincent i m not getting you :(

Comment: For a 1,000 row array the HTML formatting takes less than a a tenth of a second. The output HTML size is about 2 megabytes. I used your `<td>` layout to generate the contents so it is a fair representation of the string processing required.